# Optimizing Excel CountIfs - can I make it go faster?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some larger files I need to validate the data in.  I have most of it automated to input the formulas I need automatically.  This helps eliminate errors of copy and paste on large files.  The problem is with this latest validation.

One of the latest validations involves counting the number of rows that match 3 columns.  The 3 columns are in Sheet 2 and the rows to count are in Sheet 1.  Then compare this count with an expected number based on Sheet 2.  It is easy enough to do with CountIFs, but there are large files and it can take up to an hour on some of them.  I am trying to find something faster.

I am using a smaller file and it is still taking about 1 minute.  There are only about 1800 rows.

I have something like this:

[image]

[image]

In Check1 I am using: =COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,B2,Sheet1!C:C,C2)

My code puts that formula in the active cell.  Is there a better way to do this?

Is there anyway - using VB or anything - to improve the performance.
When the rows start getting into the 10's of thousands it is time to start this and get lunch.  And, then hope it is done when I get back to my desk!

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code.  It is not the formula that is causing the delay.

Comment: I think he is only using the countifs function at this point.

Comment: ActiveCell.Offset(0,6).FormulaR1C1 = "COUNTIFS(...."
Also tried ActiveCell.Offset(0,6).Value = "COUNTIFS(..."

Comment: we need to see the full loop, the problem lays in the fact that you are using select and activecell.

Comment: Are you using VBA to write this formula into EVERY ROW?? That will be slow. Write the formula once and copy it down.

Comment: If the formula is in place, how long does a recalc take?

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to iterate over all rows for each column, this is expensive. You might be able to split this into two tasks:

1. Merge your Columns A-C into one value `=CONCAT(A2,B2,C2)`
2. Then do only a single countif on this column `=COUNTIF(D:D,D2)`

That way you get rid of two (time) expensive countifs at the cost of the new concat.

Comment: Countifs is not time expensive. It's very fast. The delay is more likely in the VBA loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should narrow the range CountIf acts on from entire columns to the actual used range

And your code could write the result of the formula instead of the formula itself

Like follows:

```
With Sheet1
    Set sheet1Rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:C"))
End With

With Sheet2
    For Each cell in Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A"))
        cell.Offset(,3) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(sheet1Rng.Columns(1), cell.Value, sheet1Rng.Columns(2), cell.Offset(,1).Value, sheet1Rng.Columns(3),cell.Offset(2).Value)
    Next cell
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I set up a mock sheet, using a layout similar to what you show, with 10,000 rows, and manually filled it with the `COUNTIFS` formula you show.  Changing a single item in the data triggered a recalculation which took about ten seconds or so to execute.

I then tried the following macro, which executed in well under one second.  All of the counting is done within the VBA macro.  So this Dictionary method may be an answer to your speed problems.

Before running this, you may want to set the Calculation state to Manual (or do it in the code) if you have COUNTIFS on the worksheet.

---

```
Option Explicit
'set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub CountCol123()
    Dim DCT As Dictionary
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim sKey As String

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet2")

'read the info into an array
With WS
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=4)
    V = R
End With

'Get count of the matches
Set DCT = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(V, 1)
    sKey = V(I, 1) & "|" & V(I, 2) & "|" & V(I, 3)
    If DCT.Exists(sKey) Then
        DCT(sKey) = DCT(sKey) + 1
    Else
        DCT.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=1
    End If
Next I

'Get the results and write them out
For I = 2 To UBound(V, 1)
    sKey = V(I, 1) & "|" & V(I, 2) & "|" & V(I, 3)
    V(I, 4) = DCT(sKey)
Next I

'If you have COUNTIFS on the worksheet when testing this,
' or any other formulas that will be triggered,
' then uncomment the next line
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With R
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = V
End With

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The Excel alternative named Cell in Hancom Office 2020 is insanely fast at countifs. Not sure why. On my i7-5775C, Excel 2019 takes 90 seconds for a countifs with two criteria for populating 10,000 rows with the results. Using Cell, the exact same operation completes in less than 28 seconds. I have verified that the results match those generated by Excel 2019.